# Union of intervals and $\mathbb{R}$-equidescomposability

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

> Prove that if two finite union of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}$-equidescomposable, then they must have the same total length.

It is said as hint that I should consider the case when both sets consist of a single interval, and then show that the length of this two interval cannot differ by more than a factor of two. Finally, Iterate the process to conclude the result.

I do not know the way to use the hint. I mean, in order to use the definitions and assumptions, we have that

$$[a,b]=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\, A_i  $$
$$[c,d]=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\, A_i+g_i $$

Where $\{A_i\}_i$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and $\{A_i+g_i\}_i$ is a partition of $[c,d]$. How can I relate the $A_i$ and $A_i+g_i$ sets with the length of the intervals. Maybe, I attacking this problem by the wrong way.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what to make of the hint, but there is a proof of the statement you ask in Stan Wagon's book *The Banach-Taski Paradox*, corollary 10.9 on p.156.  More precisely, there is a translation-invariant finitely additive measure defined on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which extends Lebesgue measure (in particular, the length of intervals).  The key ingredients are (1) a finitely additive measure extension theorem (which relies on the axiom of choice) and (2) the fact that the group of translations of $\mathbb{R}$ is abelian, hence amenable.

Comment: I really prefer a more elementary proof.

Comment: I have been reading this notes https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/245b-notes-2-amenability-the-ping-pong-lemma-and-the-banach-tarski-paradox-optional/ then i think there is a more elementary proof.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "elementary". Tao's notes are all over the place about amenability, and the amenability of real translations is the key fact used by Wagon's proof, so what, exactly, would you like to avoid, in order to call the proof "elementary"?  (There *is* the question of the Axiom of Choice, which Wagon uses and Tao seems to say is not necessary for the result you quoted, but you didn't mention that so far.)

Comment: I mean answer that don't use concepts as measure. I think he waits for a proof that uses less machinery.

Comment: I find it very strange that you should want to avoid the concept of "measure" (or call it "machinery") on a question which you yourself tagged "measure-theory", and when the word "measure" occurs all over the place in Tao's note… (Also note that we're talking finitely additive measures here, which are more elementary than ordinary countably additive measures.)  But maybe you can get the answer you want by asking for a proof that does not use AC.

Comment: The word is used but he never really use measure concepts. He do this notes avoiding the measure theory, he only remarks that the appropriated context to a general theory for G-paradoxical sets need to use this theory.

Comment: I tagged measure theory because is the correct context but I prefer to solve the problem using the tools he gives in the paper.